# Form nested nested Json Html and Angular

Tags: html, json, angular, nested, angular-cli

I encounter a problem when I want to input data from an html form into a nested JSON object.
Example JSON:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "firstName": "Joanna",
    "lastName": "Walec",
    "salary": 5000.0,
    "department": "Analytics",
    "vacation": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "address": {
        "id": 6,
        "zipCode": 57532,
        "street": "Angular",
        "number": 2,
        "city": "New York",
        "country": "USA"
    }
}
```

Id's are auto incremented and the relationship is one-to-one. The request works with backend.
Here is the HTML form from which you input the required data:

```
<form #addForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addEmployee(addForm)">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                          <input type="text" ngModel name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="first name" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                          <input type="text" ngModel name="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="last name" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="department">Department</label>
                          <input type="text" ngModel name="department" class="form-control" id="department" placeholder="department" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="salary">Salary</label>
                          <input type="number" ngModel name="address.salary" class="form-control" id="salary" placeholder="salary" min="0" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="zipCode">Zip code</label>
                          <input type="number" ngModel name="zipCode" class="form-control" id="zipCode" placeholder="zip code" min="10000" max="99999" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="street">Street</label>
                          <input type="text" ngModel name="street" class="form-control" id="street" placeholder="street" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="number">Number</label>
                          <input type="number" ngModel name="number" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="number" min="1" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="city">City</label>
                          <input type="text" ngModel name="city" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="city" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="country">Country</label>
                          <input type="text" ngModel name="country" class="form-control" id="country" placeholder="country" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" id="add-employee-form" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          <button [disabled]="addForm.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                      </div>
                  </form>
```

And my angular function addEmployee(addForm: NgForm)

```
 public addEmployee(addForm: NgForm): void{
    this.employeeService.addEmployee(addForm.value).subscribe(
      (response : Employee) =>{
        console.log(response);
        addForm.reset();
      }
    );
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pucNL.png)

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your question is not clear. could you please mention whats your real requirement ?

Comment: Exactly, What you want?

Comment: share how you are constructing the object you send to you backend api

Comment: share how you are constructing the object you send to you backend api

Comment: share how you are constructing the object you send to you backend api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="salary">Salary</label>
  <input type="number" ngModel name="address.salary" class="form-control" id="salary" placeholder="salary" min="0" required>
</div>
```

, please use below code :

```
  <div class="form-group" ngModelGroup="address">
     <label for="salary">Salary</label>
     <input type="number" ngModel name="salary" class="form-control" id="salary" placeholder="salary" min="0" required>
  </div>
```